# How to capture remove focus from table row by JQuery

Tags: jquery

just tell me how to capture remove focus from table row by jquery. below is sample table. when user click on any cell or any cell having input controls then when user click outside of table row then i need to capture that and also need to know table row number from where focus removed. looking for help like how to achieve this by jquery. thanks

```
<table id="myTable">           
            <tr>
                <td>
                    cell4
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell5
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell6
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td >
                    cell 12
                </td>
                <td >
                    cell8
                </td>
                <td  rowspan="2">
                    cell8
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td >
                    cell9
                </td>
                <td >
                    cell10
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: The `:focus` pseudo-class typically works with input elements. What kind of "focus" behaviour are you concerned about when working with table rows/cells? A mouse enter, mouse out or etc.?

Comment: when mouse will be out from table row that i need to capture